# ActiveX script to c# - Right function in C#

Tags: c#, activex

I want to replace below code into c#. 
Right("00" & ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["KEY_NAME_VALUE"].ToString() + 1, 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't exist in C# from my knowledge
try

```
String.Substring(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["KEY_NAME_VALUE"].ToString().Length - 3)
```

Or you could use this function from Microsoft.VisualBasic

```
Public Function Right(ByVal [str] As String, ByVal Length As Integer) As String
            If Length < 0 Then
                Throw New ArgumentException(GetResourceString(ResID.Argument_GEZero1, "Length"))
            End If

            If Length = 0 OrElse [str] Is Nothing Then
                Return ""
            End If

            Dim lStrLen As Integer

            lStrLen = [str].Length

            If Length >= lStrLen Then
                Return [str]
            End If

            Return [str].Substring(lStrLen - Length, Length)
        End Function
```

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Strings.vb,0dbb15fffce19341

but then you would be relying on having `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace I suppose.

Comment: Hi Jordan. Right function comes up loads of time in my code. I am familiar with c# code but not in vb. now i am stuck with **Right("0" & Month(Now()), 2)**

Comment: Did you make your own function for the Right code or did you just use the `String.Substring` ?